# grunt plugin: svg-sprite configuration issues.

Tags: node.js, svg, sass, gruntjs

i am using grunt "svg-sprites" plugin.

cannot find a way to output variables in my scss output. 
it outputs static background-positions.

1.cannot understand how to add a "scss" "mustach" template.
2.cannot find option to define "scss" variables in the output.

will appreciate any help. 
tnx.